# How to make Vuetify grid same height as inner component

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

[image]

I'm trying to build a webpage with vuetify and nuxt.  I have:

```
 <v-app id="inspire">

<v-container justify-center style="max-width: 1200px">
          <v-layout row justify-space-around>

    <v-flex justify-center >
      <v-expansion-panel style="max-width: 1200px">
        <v-expansion-panel-content v-for="(item,i) in items" :key="i">
          <div slot="header">{{item.header}}</div>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-text>{{item.text}}</v-card-text>
          </v-card>
        </v-expansion-panel-content>
      </v-expansion-panel>
    </v-flex>
  </v-layout>
</v-container>
```

This is centering the expansion panel and its at the top. The problem is that now there is a big gap at the bottom until the next component. Please see screenshot. How do I set the grid up so its basically the same height as the expansion panel so there is no gap ?

Comment: please add more details to this [`codepen`](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/omNgxK?&editable=true&editors=101) in order to debug it

Comment: On your screenshot I don't see any component after

Comment: I think that if you place your second component outside of `<v-container>`, it will be pushed below. Try to place it in the `<v-container>`

Comment: I ended up using just the v-container and v-flex box and getting rid of the layout